# Android accelerometer reading 0 on z axys without change

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I'm creating an app that makes use of accelerometer data to calculate device roll and pitch.
This is what I have for now, still haven't coded the roll/pitch calculations.

Just checking to see which sensors are present and listing them in logcat, checking if device has accelerometer, and implementing a simple output GUI (4 textviews, corresponding to the 3 axes and max sensor range).

X and Y read correctly with phone stationary and rotating along one axys at a time, and go from 0 to around 9.5 (which would correspond to the normal 9.8m/s2 corresponding to earth's gravity force). Shaking the device results in values going over the 9.8 threshold, as expected.

Z acceleration (sensorEvent.values[2]), however, is stationary at around 0.032 (lets call it a zero). Shaking, rotating, everything short of throwing it against a wall produces absolutely no change... Which renders any of my attempts to calculate roll and pitch pretty much useless...

Is there anything wrong with this code, or should I assume something is wrong with this particular phone (tested it with my wife's phone which is exactly the same model: same results).

- Accelerometer is a KXTJ2-1009 3-axis Accelerometer (its the phones
  only physical sensor)
- Phone is a chinese-made HTM phone (suppose its a HTC clone)
  (http://www.everbuying.com/product555984.html)

  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener {

  ```
  private TextView raw_x, raw_y, raw_z, acc_max;

  private boolean hasAccelerometer;
  private SensorManager senSensorManager;
  private Sensor senAccelerometer;
  private long lastUpdate = 0;
  private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
  private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 700;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      sMgr = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
      List<Sensor> list = sMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

      String data = new String();

      for (Sensor sensor : list) {
          data += (sensor.getName() + "\n");
          data += (sensor.getVendor() + "\n");
          data += (sensor.getVersion() + "\n");
      }

      Log.d(TAG, data);

      PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
      hasAccelerometer = manager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);

      if(hasAccelerometer) {
          senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
          senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
          senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }

      Log.d(TAG,Float.toString(senAccelerometer.getMaximumRange()));

      initGui();    
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();    
  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
      Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;


      if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

          long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

          float x = (float) sensorEvent.values[0];
          float y = (float) sensorEvent.values[1];
          float z = (float) sensorEvent.values[2];

          if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
              long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
              lastUpdate = curTime;
              float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;

              if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                  //doSomething()
              }

              if(raw_x!=null){
                  raw_x.setText(Float.toString(x));
                  raw_y.setText(Float.toString(y));
                  raw_z.setText(Float.toString(z));
              }

              last_x = x;
              last_y = y;
              last_z = z;
          }
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

  }

  private void initGui() {
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      raw_x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_raw_x);
      raw_y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_raw_y);
      raw_z = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_raw_z);

      acc_max = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_max);
      acc_max.setText(Float.toString(senAccelerometer.getMaximumRange()));
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is normal, since Z-axis depends on magnetic orientation. Without a gyroscope, magnetometer or compass the z-value will most likely always be 0. Or at least remain unchanged.
Since this phone of mine has none of those, that clears it up.